# Need help fixing code so that it can complie

Tags: c, syntax-error

As part of an assignment, I have to write a code in C to give the end time when the start time and duration are added together.

For instance, "Start time is 1245. Duration is 345. End time is 1630"

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void addTime(int start, int duration);
int main()

{
 addTime(1045, 345);
 addTime(800, 435);
 addTime(2300, 300);
}

void addTime(int start, int duration)

if(start + duration > 2400)
{
 printf("Start time is %d. Duration is %d. End time is %d\n", start, duration, (((((60*(start/100))+(((start/100)%)*100)) + ((60*(duration/100))+(((duration/100)%)*100)))/60) + (((((((60*(start/100))+(((start/100)%)*100)) + ((60*(duration/100))+(((duration/100)%)*100))/60)%)/3600)%))));
}

else
{
 printf("Start time %d. Duration is %d. End time is %d\n", start, duration, (((((60*(start/100))+(((start/100)%)*100)) + ((60*(duration/100))+(((duration/100)%)*100)))/60) + (((((60*(start/100))+(((start/100)%)*100)) + ((60*(duration/100))+(((duration/100)%)*100)))/60)%));
}
```

This is the error message:

```
task3.c: In function ‘addTime’:
task3.c:14:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘if’
 if(start + duration > 2400)
task3.c:19:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘else’
 else
task3.c:22:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
```

Comment: The addTime() function needs an opening curly brace, `{`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the curly braces (`{}`) around `addTime`'s implementation:

```
void addTime(int start, int duration) 
{ /* here */    
    if(start + duration > 2400)
    {
        printf("Start time is %d. Duration is %d. End time is %d\n", start, duration, (((((60*(start/100))+(((start/100)%)*100)) + ((60*(duration/100))+(((duration/100)%)*100)))/60) + (((((((60*(start/100))+(((start/100)%)*100)) + ((60*(duration/100))+(((duration/100)%)*100))/60)%)/3600)%))));
    }        
    else
    {
        printf("Start time %d. Duration is %d. End time is %d\n", start, duration, (((((60*(start/100))+(((start/100)%)*100)) + ((60*(duration/100))+(((duration/100)%)*100)))/60) + (((((60*(start/100))+(((start/100)%)*100)) + ((60*(duration/100))+(((duration/100)%)*100)))/60)%));
    }
} /* and here */
```